# Why can't I access HTTP server running on my machine from outside the local network?

Tags: webserver, sockets

I'm running a HTTP server on my Ubuntu 20.04 on port 8000 using python3.

I already did the port-fowarding on my router (and also tested by hosting a Minecraft server and asking a friend to join) but I can't access it from outside.

I checked UFW and it is **disabled**. But I allowed the port anyway, just to be sure.

```
sudo ufw status 
Status: inactive
```

Log from nmap:

```
# Local

PORT     STATE SERVICE
8000/tcp open  http-alt

# Global

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
8000/tcp filtered http-alt
```

Here are some things that other people suggested to look in order to find the problem, but to no avail.

```
netstat -tulpn

(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26914/python3       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:44604           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp6       0      0 :::44370                :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                -
```

I though that maybe my Router is blocking the requests but I don't know how to verify and it is weird since it's not blocking the Minecraft Server.

Comment: Are you forwarding port 8000 external to 8000 internal? Are you placing the :8000 at the end of the address when you type it into a web browser while browsing remotely?

Comment: @SamForbis I'm doing exactly like this! For local access I use **localhost:8000** and for global I use **<my_public_ip>:8000**.